# How exactly does CASCADE work with ManyToMany Fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models, cascade

Im Wondering how exactly does CASCADE work with ManyToMany Fields in Django.

A short example:

```
class Project(Model):
    name = TextField(null=False)

class Job(Model):
    projects = ManyToManyField(Project, on_delete=CASCADE, null=False)
    name = TextField(null=False)
```

As you can see I have a ManyToManyField here. So basically a Project can have mutiple Jobs and a Job can belong to Multiple different Projects. What I want is that a Job is automatically deleted only when all Projects it belongs to are deleted. Does CASCADE work like that in this scenario?

Comment: it deletes all chained rows linked with cascaded tables.

Comment: It delets the rows related (all jobs) when the project itself is deleted, It's totally useless in your case, Have a look at signals, or the model manager method `.clear()` and manually implement the logic you want

Answer (score 1):

CASCADE doesn't work like that. In your case, with CASCADE, with two projects A and B, a job J_DAILY linked to both projects, if you delete project A, then J_DAILY will be deleted too.

If you want your job to "live to its last project". You should change your `on_delete` to `DO_NOTHING` and add a check on deleting projects.

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Project)
def delete_related_jobs(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for job in instance.job_set.all():
        # No remaining projects
        if not job.projects.exclude(id=instance.id).count():
               job.delete()
```